# How to implement PID position control for 4wheel mecanum robot?

Tags: pid, wheeled-robot

I want to implement PID control on my 4 wheel mecanun robot. I want to give a position instruction to my robot and that it follow the following curves of velocity and position. The only feedback that my robot have is an encoder on each wheel . How can I code this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Charles, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Your question title makes it seem like you want help implementing a PID controller, but the body of your question seems like you want help generating the S-curve for your position profile. Could you please clarify what you want to do, what you've tried, and why you think it's not working?